# Fill an array with dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, byref

Really can't see why the dates I'm pushing into an array are not the dates that come out when I call the array in the console. i.e. I would expect the first entry in the array to be today's date, which is what comes back from both alert calls, but when I check the array's first position it has yesterday's date instead!?

```
function sevenDayPeriod(date) {

    for (var i = 0; i <=6; i++) {

        alert(date);    //check to see date is today's date
        dateRange[i] = date;
        alert(dateRange[i]);    //confirm that what I've pushed to array is today's date

        date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        date = new Date(date);
    }
};

var dateRange = [];
var today  = new Date();

sevenDayPeriod(today);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
...
dateRange[i] = date;
alert(dateRange[i]);    //confirm that what I've pushed to array is today's date
date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
...
```

In the first of the above lines you set the ith array element to `date` (a reference), then you show it and afterwards you change the same object with `setDate` which results in your problem, as the array element still points to that modified object.
You can solve that e.g. with another var like so

```
...
var prevDay = new Date();
prevDay.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
date = prevDay;
...
```

or create a copy of it prior to pushing it into the array

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes perfect sense and hopefully something I'll learn from!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sevenDayPeriod(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i <=6; i++) {
 //date object is as a "pointer", you have to clone it
 var copiedDate = new Date(date);
  
        //alert(date); //check to see date is today's date
        dateRange[i] = copiedDate;
        //alert(dateRange[i]); //confirm that what I've pushed to array is today's date
  
        date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        date = new Date(date);
    }
};

var dateRange = [];
var today  = new Date();

sevenDayPeriod(today);

console.log(dateRange);
```

When you modify the date, you are you're also changing pushed date. You have to clone it.